# How to plot all possible (x,y) points with two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])    
Y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

I need to plot with scatter  these point ==>  (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),...,(5,3),(5,4),(5,5)

If we try:

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])   
Y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])      
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

result is only these point ==> (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)

Specifically, I am trying to mark all possible (x, y) binaries that can be created from the given x and y binaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `meshgrid` function: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

```
A,B = np.meshgrid(X,Y)                                                                                      
plt.scatter(A,B)
```

Comment: thx for answer , can we print all these (x,y) variables ?

Comment: Sure @EnesA, just do: `all_pnts = np.stack((A,B), axis=2).reshape(-1,2) `

Comment: thx for help :D

Answer (score 1):

```
all_pts_x, all_pts_y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
ax.scatter(all_pts_x, all_pts_y)
```

[image]